# Differences of Bug tracking in Agile process and Scrum process of VSTS 2017?

Tags: azure-devops

With the ability to [configure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog) how the bugs should manage, I'm confuse what to select as a process when I create a team project in VSTS 2017.

In the [Microsoft guidance](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/choose-process) they say Agile

> works great if you want to track user stories and **(optionally)** bugs on the Kanban board, or track bugs and tasks on the task board.

But even I select Scrum as the process, the bugs can be configure not to manage on the Kanban board.

and further

> Choose Agile when your team uses Agile planning methods, including Scrum, and **tracks development and test activities separately**.

Isn't this same even I select Scrum as the process? I couldn't see any differences from the interfaces.

Of cause by choosing, Agile I can track original estimation and the completed work alone with the reaming work.

So what are the other differences, which I go for a one over the other? May be some reports like [Stories Overview Report](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/sql-reports/stories-overview-report-agile)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Bug tracking, the workflows are different: [Workflow states, transitions, and reasons.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/choose-process#workflow-states-transitions-and-reasons)

For Agile process, the forecasting is based on Story Points and for Scrum process, it is based on Effort.

Regarding report, the link you provide is used for on-premises TFS. You can show report that you want in the custom widget or hub extension, so no difference.

[Write your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

Comment: Does agile tracks test activities separately? Scrum doesn't?

Comment: @Geeganage Do not find the difference of tracing test in agile and scrum. Both of them can to do work with test in Test tab (need to install Test Management extension), also the test can be added/tracked in Kanban board.